# How to think about projective geometry problems

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space

This semester I am taking an introductory course on projective geometry. Even though I believe I understand the different theoretical concepts correctly (supplementary varieties, [Grassmann Formula](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Grassmann), etc.) more often than not I find myself completely baffled when trying to attempt different problems.

For instance, one I was working on recently was:

"In a projective space of dimension four, $\mathbb{P}_4$, let $\pi_1, \pi_2$ be two planes that intersect at point, $\pi_1 \cap \pi_2 = \{p\}$, and let r be a line that passes through $p$ and that isn't contained in $\pi_1$ nor in $\pi_2$. Prove that there exists a unique plane $\pi$ that contains $r$ and s.t. the intersections $\pi \cap \pi_1$, $\pi \cap \pi_1$ are lines."

My problem is that when faced with problems like this I don't know how to start. Since we are working in a dimension higher than 3, I don't have any kind of geometrical intuition (for instance, if we were in dimension 3 I believe I could think of $\mathbb{P}_3$ simply as an affine space of dimension 3, completed with points at infinity). I have seen the solution to the problem, in which the main idea is to think about a supplementary variety to $p$, but I don't know how someone would come to think of that. So, my question is, how should one tackle this kinds of problems?

Also, any recommendations for a projective geometry book in which explicit, step-by-step solutions to problems are given would be very much welcome.

Comment: Have a look at all the questions on math SE with tags "geometry"  "projective geometry", etc. Many techniques are used there.

Comment: @JeanMarie did you have any particular question in mind that you could link? I have been looking at the tags you mention but haven't found any questions that really focus on how someone who solves the problem tackles it, (i.e. what motivates the different constructions they employ in the resolution, what is the intuition).

Comment: Think geometrically, prove algebraically.
—John Tate

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/projective-geometry in general with for example the supplementary tag "motivation" : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402323/books-about-synthetic-projective-geometry/3404841#3404841, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815546/motivation-behind-definition-of-projective-space, etc.